# Spring aop attempted duplicate class definition

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

Would anyone have ideas why this is happening? The error only happens on first access. After that, everything is fine.

In Spring AOP under Tomcat, advising methods in a single class works fine:

```
@Around("execution(* com.test.TestController.*(..))")
```

or

```
@Around("execution(* com.test.UserController.*(..))")
```

they both work if I use them separately. If I use both:

```
@Around("execution(* com.test.TestController.*(..)) || execution(* com.test.UserController.*(..))")
```

it blows up:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader (instance of  tomcat/servletcontainer/PlugInOverrideClassLoader): attempted  duplicate class definition for name: "com/test//UserController$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$4936077f"
```

Seems I can advise a single class but not more than one. Advising all classes in a package has the same effect.

Comment: Which Tomcat version do you use?

Comment: not sure, it's running as a webapp inside Blackboard